# Proving a theorem about Fourier coefficients

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces

I need to prove this:

> Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function on $[-\pi, \pi]$. Prove that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ satisfy $|a_n| \leq \frac{K}{n}$ for some constant $K$.

Can someone please let me know if I would be on a right track if I said:

Let $||f(x)||_\infty$ = C, then $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) \cos(nx) dx \leq \frac{2}{\pi} C \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(nx) dx = \frac{2}{\pi} C \frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \leq C \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{K}{n}$.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $\|f(x)-f\|_{\infty}$, you are using the same function $f$ twice, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out. Can we define $f(x)$ in the integral in terms of a sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ and then proceed in this way? A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think your proof is correct. A continues function on a compact interval should attain a maximum value [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) \cos nx dx=\frac{1}{n}f(x)\sin nx\mid_{-\pi}^\pi-1/n\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{df}{dx}\sin nx dx=-1/n\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{df}{dx}\sin nx dx\\\implies \left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x) \cos nx dx\right|=\frac{1}{n}\left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{df}{dx}\sin nx dx\right|\\\le \frac{1}{n}\max_{x\in [-\pi,\pi]}\left|\frac{df}{dx}\right|\left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin nx dx\right|$$ Since $f\in \mathcal{C}^1, \frac{df}{dx}$ is continuous and hence takes a finite maximum value over $[-\pi,\pi]$(since this set is compact) and thus $|a_n|$ becomes bounded.

Comment: Awesome. However, I'm wondering if we could use $||f(x)||_\infty = C$  and doing the same operations without "expanding" the integral?

Comment: I am do using something like $\|f\|_\infty$ but I will have to think about it if there is a way without using the integration. That just came very natural to me.

Comment: The thing is that in this case $a_n$ seems to be less than or equal to 0.

Answer (score 2):

More easily you can do this:

$a_n(f)=-\frac {b_n(f')}{n}$ and by Riemann-Lebesgue lemma we have that $b_n(f')\to 0$ and thus $|b_n(f')|\leq K$ for every $n$ and  we have that $|a_n| \leq \frac{K}{n}$.